# Update UI upon received SMS

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I use code from http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android as reference.
I added scrollview and it show the append text upon sms send out.

however i have problem append incoming sms text in the same scrollview.
how can i solve it? do i need to use thread, service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Broadcast Receiver to Hook onto incomming SMS....Fire an Intent (with SMS Body as an Extra) to Trigger your Activity (your link will help with that)...in the `onStart()` or `onNewIntent()` you grab the Extra and update your UI...

Another Method would be to use a `ContentObserver` for `content://sms/` but that's advised against unless your sure the Messaging App will intercept the SMS.

Untested Code!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,YourActivity.class); //context from onRecieve(context,intentData)
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //required if ur app is not currently running.
intent.putExtra("SMSBODY",smsbody); //get smsbody from the getMessageBody() (from your link)
context.startActivity(intent);
```

In your Activity...In `onStart()` or `onNewIntent()`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent.getStringExtra("SMSBODY") != null)
{
String msg = intent.getStringExtra("SMSBODY");
//append msg to scroll view
}
```

Comment: still having problem with passing the intent. can you provide some examples?

Comment: @conandor, Added some code that might guide you better, though i couldn't test it, don't have access to my dev machine. :(

Comment: Yes, I have the same code. but It keep launching the new textview upon receiving the message

Comment: Problem solved. On receiving part codes as below. Thankx st0le!

Comment: public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
 String msg = intent.getStringExtra("SMSBODY");
}

Comment: @conandor, that's great, but make sure you put a `null` check, onNewIntent() maybe called for other reasons as well, and those `Intent`'s wont have your extra.

Comment: What if my activity alread started and I just want to update it?

Comment: @complez, Your activity should be `singleInstance` and I believe `onNewIntent` will be called in that case.

Comment: To add to the comment above by @st0le, if you make use of `startActivityForResult()` in your app, then consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118525/onactivityresult-do-not-fire-if-launch-mode-of-activity-is-singleinstance .. in short, use launchMode `singleTask` instead of `singleInstance`