# onActivityResult do not fire if launch mode of activity is singleInstance

Tags: android, android-activity, single-instance

I have an Activity which is basically my main activity and its launch mode is single instance. But because of singleInstance, the `onActivityResult()` callback does not fire. And if  I change the launch mode in my manifest file to any other mode it works fine.

Can you explain why this callback is not working?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I believe that the problem is that singleInstance doesn't let the callee activity to exist in the same task as the caller, hence it can't return the value to the caller.

Consider using singleTask instead:

**singleTask**

> The system creates the activity at the
>   root of a new task and routes the
>   intent to it. However, if an instance
>   of the activity already exists, the
>   system routes the intent to existing
>   instance through a call to its
>   onNewIntent() method, rather than
>   creating a new one.

**singleInstance**

> Same as "singleTask", except that the
>   system doesn't launch any other
>   activities into the task holding the
>   instance. The activity is always the
>   single and only member of its task.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: If `onActivityResult` depends on having both parent and child in the same task, shouldn't that be documented somewhere???  I'm dealing with an intermittent failure to call through `onActivityResult` wtf.

Comment: I don't believe this is correct, I tried it and SingleTask did not fire onActivityResult when it finished.  This StackOverflow seems to indicate the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960072/onactivityresult-with-launchmode-singletask

Comment: @jt-gilkeson the question you linked to is talking about the launch mode of the **target** `Activity` (ie: the one you are trying to launch. OP's question is talking about the launch mode of the **calling** `Activity` (ie: the one calling `startActivityForResult()`). This answer is correct  because an `Activity` with launch mode `singleTask` **can** launch other activities into its task (but an `Activity` with launch mode `singleInstance` cannot).

Answer (score 5):

If an activity is `singleInstance`, it will be the only one in the task so it always be the top of the task. So when you call `startActivityForResult` it will fire the callback method immediately.

Answer (score 4):

A "[singleInstance](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)" activity,  permits no other activities to be part of its task. It's the only activity in the task. If it starts another activity, that activity is assigned to a different task. The activity is always the single and only member of its task.
I think `onActivityResult` will not work with `singleInstance`

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `singleInstance` or `singleTask` with `startActivityForResult` method.

Standard mode or singleTop launch mode will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Android Source Code](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityStarter.java#1380)

Check "ActivityStarter.computeLaunchingTaskFlags()" method:

```
            } else if (mSourceRecord.launchMode == LAUNCH_SINGLE_INSTANCE) {
            // The original activity who is starting us is running as a single
            // instance...  this new activity it is starting must go on its
            // own task.
            mLaunchFlags |= FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;
```

That's the reason why NEW_TASK flag is added when your original activity with single instance launch mode.

[More Source Code](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityStarter.java#1364)

Check  "ActivityStarter.sendNewTaskResultRequestIfNeeded()" method:

```
        if (sourceStack != null && (mLaunchFlags & FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) != 0) {
        // For whatever reason this activity is being launched into a new task...
        // yet the caller has requested a result back.  Well, that is pretty messed up,
        // so instead immediately send back a cancel and let the new task continue launched
        // as normal without a dependency on its originator.
        Slog.w(TAG, "Activity is launching as a new task, so cancelling activity result.");
        sourceStack.sendActivityResultLocked(-1 /* callingUid */, mStartActivity.resultTo,
                mStartActivity.resultWho, mStartActivity.requestCode, RESULT_CANCELED,
                null /* data */);
```

That's the reason why FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK always immediately return RESULT_CANCELED.

Answer (score 0):

An example of my application can benefit someone:

- In the manifest file, my settings are:

`<application android:launchMode="singleTask"...>`

- I use one java class, only as a launcher(it does not show Activity). In the manifest, it is set to:

`<activity android:launchMode="singleTop" ...>`

- Also, other Activities are set the same:

`<activity android:launchMode="singleTop" ...>`

When a user sends an application to the background, by clicking on the application icon or restoring the application from the background, the last started Activity is returned unchanged, even though they were all started with `startActivityForResult()` from launcher.