# Where the package name should be changed while using zxing library in my own project

Tags: zxing

The package name of my project is com.mohit.verma
I do not want to install the zxing bar code scanner app externally.
I just want to use the library files.
So where should I change the package names?
Any help would be appreciated...
My Code is as below:

```
 barCodeScanner.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                    intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
                   // intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                    //intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Well, I'll give you three guesses...

Comment: Do you not see 3 clear package names in the snippet above to change?

Comment: I changed the package name in the above snippet, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

[setPackage() is optional](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setPackage%28java.lang.String%29).
Plenty of SO code and links from [April](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604550/calling-barcode-scanner-on-a-button-click-in-android-application) and [March](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241557/what-needs-to-be-added-to-the-android-manifest-file-for-the-zxing-barcode-scanner).