# QR code game from within android application

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I have an android application and I need to integrate QR code within it.On my phone there is installed the `Barcode Scanner` application.

What I want to do is to scan the bar and return the code into my application.
Can this be done by using an intent or I need to refer some packages into my android application??

An exact answer with what should I do will be appreciated.Thank you!

EDIT:Do I need any kind of permissions in the manifest file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [zxing on Scanning Via Intent](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent):

```
public Button.OnClickListener mScan = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            // Handle successful scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can leverage Barcode Scanner with the [IntentIntegrator](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java) and [IntentResult](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentResult.java) classes also, rather than doing it manually. It makes it very easy to use Barcode Scanner to retrieve bar codes, and even deals with cases where the user doesn't yet have Barcode Scanner installed. I used the `IntentIntegrator` class in my own app that requires scanning bar codes and retrieving the data.

Comment: Not that I know of, at least if you use the classes rather than doing it manually. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241557/what-needs-to-be-added-to-the-android-manifest-file-for-the-zxing-barcode-scanner)