# Android Concatenating onActivityResult() not triggered

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I've got three activities A, B and C. From activity A I can call activity B and from B I can call C, and I can call activity C from activity A directly as well.

The thing is that when returning the result from C directly to A through `setResult` and `onbackpressed` methods everything works fine. The problem comes when from activity C I return the result to B, and in its `onActivityResult` I call once again `setResult` and `onbackpressed` to pass that same result to activity A.

`Activity` A comes up again but in this case its `onActivityResult` is never triggered.

Here is some code.

In activity C:

```
if (selection) {
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
} else {
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, data);
}
selection = false;
super.onBackPressed();
```

In activity B get C's result and try to pass it back to activity A

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (resultCode) {
        case RESULT_OK:
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            onBackPressed();
            break;
        case RESULT_CANCELED:
            if (list_search != null && !list_search.getAdapter().isEmpty()) {
                list_search.setSelection(data.getIntExtra("position", 0));
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

And here A `onActivityResult`. I get the result either if it comes from B or from C, But its only triggering when coming directly from C. when is coming through B, A appears, but is not triggering `onActivityResult` so I can't retrieve the data in this case.

```
public void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    .... 
    switch (resultCode) {
        case RESULT_CANCELED:
            sincronizaCursorArticulos(intent.getStringExtra("cd_articulo"));
            break;

        case RESULT_OK:
            sincronizaCursorArticulos(intent.getStringExtra("cd_articulo"));
            fragment_order_entering.setEtArticulo(intent.getStringExtra("cd_articulo"));
            fragment_order_entering.loadArticulo(false);
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OnActivityResult doesnt seem to work in many cases if there is any  android:launchMode="singleTask|SingleInstance" attribute added to that respective activity which you have started with StartActivityForResult()  in the androidmanifest.xml file.

ref: [onActivityResult With launchMode="singleTask"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960072/onactivityresult-with-launchmode-singletask)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot to mention that the three activities have the singleTop launchMode.