# Android: startActivityForResult stopped calling onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I have `MainActivity` where I

```
Intent mRegister = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Register.class);
startActivity(mRegister);
```

In `Register.class` I do `startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_RESULT);` and have `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data).`

It worked, then I added some other activities and tested and run them by editing in `MainActivity`

```
Intent mRegister = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Register.class);
```

When sometime later I edited back to calling `Register.class`, `onActivityResult` is not called any more when Android returns to my application after camera run. I have not added nothing like `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to manifest etc., afaik I have not changed `Register.class` at all.

Why app could have stopped working? I suspect a glitch but maybe there is something I missed.

Answers to answers:
changing to `MainActivity.this` or `getApplicationContext()` did not make onActivityResult be called.

I tried to downgrade Android Studio from 1.5 to 1.4 - did not help, I'm using java 1.8. Tried on device with Android 4.0 and 4.4.

Logcat for selected application when MainActivity.this:

```
04-08 09:19:48.869 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:48.869 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001A9, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:48.869 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001a9)
04-08 09:19:48.870 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:48.870 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:49.370 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:49.370 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001AA, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:49.370 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001aa)
04-08 09:19:49.371 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:49.371 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:49.872 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:49.872 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001AB, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:49.872 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001ab)
04-08 09:19:49.872 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:49.872 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:50.372 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:50.372 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001AC, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:50.372 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001ac)
04-08 09:19:50.373 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:50.373 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:50.873 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:50.873 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001AD, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:50.873 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001ad)
04-08 09:19:50.874 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:50.874 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:51.374 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:51.374 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001AE, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:51.374 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001ae)
04-08 09:19:51.374 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:51.374 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:51.875 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:51.875 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001AF, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:51.875 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001af)
04-08 09:19:51.875 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:51.875 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:52.375 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:52.375 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001B0, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:52.375 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001b0)
04-08 09:19:52.376 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:52.376 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:52.425 30528-30528/com.julius.sv D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{417a2018 token=android.os.BinderProxy@417a1900 {com.julius.sv/com.julius.sv.Register}}
04-08 09:19:52.441 30528-30528/com.julius.sv D/ActivityThread: ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@417a1900
04-08 09:19:52.850 30528-30528/com.julius.sv D/ActivityThread: ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_SHOW handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@417a1900
04-08 09:19:52.877 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:52.877 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001B1, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:52.877 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001b1)
04-08 09:19:52.877 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:52.877 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:53.377 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:53.377 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001B2, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:53.377 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001b2)
04-08 09:19:53.377 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:53.378 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:53.879 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:53.879 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001B3, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:53.879 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001b3)
04-08 09:19:53.879 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:53.879 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:54.380 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:54.380 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001B4, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:54.380 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001b4)
04-08 09:19:54.380 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:54.380 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:54.854 30528-30528/com.julius.sv D/ActivityThread: ACT-HIDE_WINDOW handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@417a1900
04-08 09:19:54.858 30528-30528/com.julius.sv D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-08 09:19:54.880 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:54.881 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001B5, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:54.881 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001b5)
04-08 09:19:54.883 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:54.883 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:54.906 30528-30528/com.julius.sv D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 1)
04-08 09:19:55.382 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:55.382 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001B6, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:55.382 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001b6)
04-08 09:19:55.383 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:55.383 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:55.883 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:55.883 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001B7, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:55.883 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001b7)
04-08 09:19:55.883 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:55.887 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:56.102 30528-30528/com.julius.sv W/InputMethodManager: startInputInner : InputBindResult == null
04-08 09:19:56.103 30528-30528/com.julius.sv W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-08 09:19:56.361 30528-30528/com.julius.sv D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 2)
04-08 09:19:56.369 30528-30528/com.julius.sv D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-08 09:19:56.370 30528-30528/com.julius.sv D/OpenGLRenderer: Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-08 09:19:56.384 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:56.384 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001B8, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:56.384 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001b8)
04-08 09:19:56.385 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:56.385 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:56.885 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:56.885 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001B9, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:56.885 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001b9)
04-08 09:19:56.885 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:56.885 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:57.386 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:57.386 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001BA, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:57.386 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001ba)
04-08 09:19:57.386 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:57.386 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:57.887 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:57.887 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001BB, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:57.887 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001bb)
04-08 09:19:57.887 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:57.887 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:58.387 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:58.387 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001BC, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:58.387 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001bc)
04-08 09:19:58.387 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:58.387 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:58.888 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:58.888 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001BD, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:58.888 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001bd)
04-08 09:19:58.888 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:58.888 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:59.389 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:59.389 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001BE, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:59.389 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001be)
04-08 09:19:59.389 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:59.389 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:19:59.889 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:19:59.889 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001BF, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:19:59.889 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001bf)
04-08 09:19:59.890 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:19:59.890 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:00.441 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:00.441 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001C0, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:00.442 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001c0)
04-08 09:20:00.442 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:00.443 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:00.892 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:00.892 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001C1, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:00.892 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001c1)
04-08 09:20:00.892 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:00.892 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:01.393 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:01.393 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001C2, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:01.393 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001c2)
04-08 09:20:01.393 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:01.393 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:01.893 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:01.893 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001C3, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:01.893 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001c3)
04-08 09:20:01.893 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:01.895 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:02.340 30528-30528/com.julius.sv D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{417a2018 token=android.os.BinderProxy@417a1900 {com.julius.sv/com.julius.sv.Register}}
04-08 09:20:02.358 30528-30528/com.julius.sv D/ActivityThread: ACT-RESUME_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@417a1900
04-08 09:20:02.394 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:02.394 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001C4, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:02.394 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001c4)
04-08 09:20:02.394 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:02.394 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:02.566 30528-30528/com.julius.sv W/IInputConnectionWrapper: showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-08 09:20:02.896 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:02.896 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001C5, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:02.896 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001c5)
04-08 09:20:02.897 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:02.897 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:03.397 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:03.397 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001C6, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:03.397 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001c6)
04-08 09:20:03.397 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:03.397 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:03.898 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:03.898 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001C7, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:03.898 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001c7)
04-08 09:20:03.898 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:03.898 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:04.399 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:04.399 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001C8, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:04.399 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001c8)
04-08 09:20:04.399 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:04.399 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:04.900 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:04.900 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001C9, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:04.900 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001c9)
04-08 09:20:04.900 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:04.900 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:05.401 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:05.401 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001CA, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:05.401 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001ca)
04-08 09:20:05.402 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:05.402 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:05.902 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:05.902 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001CB, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:05.902 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001cb)
04-08 09:20:05.902 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:05.902 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:06.403 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:06.403 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001CC, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:06.403 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001cc)
04-08 09:20:06.403 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:06.403 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:06.904 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:06.904 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001CD, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:06.904 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001cd)
04-08 09:20:06.904 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:06.905 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:07.405 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:07.405 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001CE, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:07.405 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001ce)
04-08 09:20:07.405 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:07.405 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:07.905 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:07.905 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001CF, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:07.905 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001cf)
04-08 09:20:07.905 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:07.905 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:08.406 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:08.406 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001D0, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:08.406 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001d0)
04-08 09:20:08.406 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:08.407 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:08.907 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:08.907 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001D1, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:08.907 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001d1)
04-08 09:20:08.907 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:08.907 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
04-08 09:20:09.408 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: processIncoming
04-08 09:20:09.408 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: handlePacket : cmd=0x1, cmdSet=0xC7, len=0x14, id=0x400001D2, flags=0x0, dataLen=0x9
04-08 09:20:09.408 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: REQ: DDM.Chunk (cmd=199/1 dataLen=9 id=0x400001d2)
04-08 09:20:09.409 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: sendBufferedRequest : len=0x34
04-08 09:20:09.409 30528-30535/com.julius.sv D/jdwp: reply: dataLen=0 err=NONE(0)
```

Comment: Consider changing getBaseContext() to MainActivity.this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9606712/4139846)

Comment: What are the launch flags of the activity that `cameraIntent` resolves to?  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8960126/1953590.

Comment: @saeed. logcat posted

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `getBaseContext()` with `MainActivity.this`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **getBaseContext()** use **MainActivity.this** or **getApplicationContext()**

I hope it may help you.. :)