# OnActivityResult not executed

Tags: android, camera

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84y1Z.png)

When I call the system camera through the above code，the onActivityResult method does not perform on some phones,For example, Samsung S4,That's why.Ask for help

Comment: Show you onActivityResult()

Comment: Please paste your code as text in the question. Please don't post screenshots of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions:

- You should try with request code larger than 0.
- Does your activity contain **singleInstance** or **singleTask** launchMode? check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118525/onactivityresult-do-not-fire-if-launch-mode-of-activity-is-singleinstance) .

Answer (score 0):

next time please add the source code. its easier that way. 
and the logcat if some error is there.

but it seems that what you want to achieve is something like 
[Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent)