# Calling ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture() false is returned so the image isn't being saved as expected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-jetpack

I am trying to save an image from the camera and it keeps returning false. I thought the image wasn't being displayed but when I looked at the filesystem I have lots of files but they are all of length zero.

Just some set up here.

```
val pictureResult = remember { mutableStateOf<Boolean?>(null)}
val context = LocalContext.current
val cameraLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) {
    pictureResult.value = it
    // $it is false
}
```

This will create the file that is in the screenshot.

```
fun createImageFile(extension:String): File {
    // Create an image file name
    val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    val storageDir: File? = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    val imagePath: File = File(context.filesDir, directoryFromExtension(extension))
    return File(imagePath, "justme${timeStamp}${extension}"
    ).apply {
        myNewsCreatorViewModel.currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
    }
}
```

When the button is clicked I go through these steps, starting with the file returned from the previous method.

```
                val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.mine.fileprovider", file)
                cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
```

This is the result after I set the `pictureResult.value`, the idea being to then show the image, or I currently show a text message if `imageSaved` was false that the file wasn't saved.

```
        pictureResult.value?.let { imageSaved ->
            run {
                // imageSaved is false
            }
        }
```

I can't tell what I am doing wrong, and I can't tell how to get more information as to why it failed to save the image properly.

[image: Screenshot of file system showing files with length zero]

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was caused by the `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` setting in the app manifest. The contract returned false, but I could load the image from the given `URI`. After removing the setting, it started working.

Comment: It also worked for me! The reason is, for `singleInstance`, the system doesn't launch any other activities into the task holding the instance. So the activity doesn't receive the result. Instead, we can use `singleTask`. For details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5118924/2263329

Answer (score 0):

It appears the solution is to add:

```
val storageDir: File? = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), directoryFromExtension(extension))
if(storageDir?.exists() == false && ".jpg" == extension) {
    storageDir.mkdirs()
}
```

And I am not certain if it helps but it works if I also put this before I call the intent.

```
context.grantUriPermission("com.mine.android", uri,
    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
```

Comment: I have similar setup as you did and also used a `FileProvider`. So you suggested that `FileProvider` didn't create the directories for you and you had to check & create folders beforehand?

Comment: For the `GRAND_URI_PERMISSION` I think it's unnecessary because when adding `<provider>` tag into `AndroidManifest.xml`, you could add this:`android:grantUriPermissions="true"` to it

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following permissions declared in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

IMO it's always a good idea to revisit [Take photos](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) from the official docs if you're bumping into unknown issues.

Comment: I do have those but I am only support version 28+ so I put in there a max version that this is needed on.