# Flutter filepicker android singleInstance mode it is returns file path as null

Tags: android, flutter, filepicker, filepicker.io

I am using the flutter file picker 6.0.0.When i try to select file from the picker file.I used singleInstance in manifest.

```
 FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowedExtensions: ['jpg','jpeg','png','pdf'],type: FileType.custom);
if (result != null) {
  File file = File(result.files.single.path!);
  controller.isPasswordProtected.value =
      await FileHelper.checkFileIsPasswordProtected(file);
  controller.fileSelected(file);
  controller.uploadDocument();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is expected behavior on Android, you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49993984). If the calling app forbids other activities in its task, then it can't get results from other activities.

Related flutter plugin [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) is also mentioning about `singleInstance` launch mode :

> Launching the image picker from an `Activity` with `launchMode: singleInstance` will always return `RESULT_CANCELED`. In this launch mode, new activities are created in a separate [Task](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack). As activities cannot communicate between tasks, the image picker activity cannot send back its eventual result to the calling activity. To work around this problem, consider using `launchMode: singleTask` instead.

[Read the details here](https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/main/packages/image_picker/image_picker#using-launchmode-singleinstance)